# Convert Groovy map implementing an interface back to a map

Tags: groovy

When using a map of closures to implement an interface in Groovy (as in http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+way+to+implement+interfaces) is there any way to convert the object back to a map after using the as keyword or the asType method to implement the interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your use case it would seem that you could just keep a reference to the original `Map` before converting it into the needed interface.

However, looking at the source code that converts the `Map` object into the interface (using a `Proxy`), it looks like you can just re-retrieve the original map by getting the `InvocationHandler`'s delegate.

```
def i = 1
def m = [ hasNext:{ true }, next:{ i++ } ]
Iterator iter = m as Iterator

def d = java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getInvocationHandler(iter).delegate
assert d.is(m)
```

*Note: This depends on the internals of the Groovy code so use at your own risk:*

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question...  Short answer, no.  Long answer, maybe...  Assuming you have something like this:

```
def i = 1
Iterator iter = [ hasNext:{ true }, next:{ i++ } ] as Iterator
```

then calling

```
println iter.take( 3 ).collect()
```

prints `[1,2,3]`

Now, you can declare a method to do this:

```
def mapFromInterface( Object o, Class... clz ) {
  // Get a Set of all methods across the array of classes clz
  Set methods = clz*.methods.flatten()
  // Then, for each of these
  methods.collectEntries {
    // create a map entry with the name of the method as the key
    // and a closure which invokes the method as a value
    [ (it.name): { Object... args ->
                   o.metaClass.pickMethod( it.name, it.parameterTypes ).invoke( o, args )
    } ]
  }
}
```

This then allows you to do:

```
def map = mapFromInterface( iter, Iterator )
```

And calling:

```
println map.next()
println map.next()
```

Will print `4` followed by `5`

printing the map with `println map` gives:

```
[ remove:ConsoleScript43$_mapFromInterface_closure3_closure4@57752bea,
  hasNext:ConsoleScript43$_mapFromInterface_closure3_closure4@4d963c81,
  next:ConsoleScript43$_mapFromInterface_closure3_closure4@425e60f2 ]
```

**However**, as this is a map, any class which contains multiple methods with the same name and different arguments will fail.  I am also not sure how wise it is to do this in the first case...

What is your use-case out of interest?

Comment: I use Groovy a lot for writing unit tests for Java code and frequently use maps of closures as quick and dirty way to stub out interfaces that my unit under test depends on (as I find it easier than most mocking libraries when I don't really care about verifying the interactions).  Sometimes I want to set up a "prototype" stubbed interface and just tweak it a little bit for different test scenarios but I can't do that without being able to convert it back to a map.

Comment: @WillGorman For your use case, [plecong's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9507914/6509) is probably better and cleaner than mine :-)